# Remove duplicates from nested list based on a string and a value

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list like this:

```
[['john', 14, 'USA'],['john', 27, 'USA'],['paul', 17, 'USA'],['paul', 36, 'USA']]
```

And need to get as output:

```
[['john', 27, 'USA'],['paul', 36, 'USA']]
```

This means to remove duplicates based on position 0 but keep the ones with the higher value in position 1.

I know how to remove duplicates on regular lists using `set()`, but how do I go about applying those 2 conditions? I was thinking something with a `for` but i might be very slow since the real lists I'll use are very large.

I already tried to remove duplicates just by names but I'm puzzled about keeping the one with the higher value.

Thanks!

Comment: This is a very specific requirement, there isn't going to be a ready-made solution, you're going to have to loop through things.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `itertools.groupby` for grouping your elements by first index and `max` function with a proper `key` to select the max based on second element :

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> l=[['john', 14, 'USA'], ['john', 27, 'USA'], ['paul', 17, 'USA'], ['paul', 36, 'USA']]
>>> [max(g ,key=lambda x:x[1]) for _,g in groupby(sorted(l),lambda x: x[0])]
[['john', 27, 'USA'], ['paul', 36, 'USA']]
```

Or as a more efficient way you can use `operators.itemgetter()` instead `lambda` :

```
>>> from operators import itemgetter
>>> [max(g ,key=itemgetter(1)) for _,g in groupby(sorted(l),itemgetter(0))]
[['john', 27, 'USA'], ['paul', 36, 'USA']]
```

Answer (score 1):

I like Kasra's solution, but jsut to give another way to do it:

```
from collections import defaultdict

l=[['john', 14, 'USA'], ['john', 27, 'USA'], ['paul', 17, 'USA'], ['paul', 36, 'USA']]
key=defaultdict(list)
for n,a,c in l:
    key[(n,c)].append(a)
f_list = [[k[0],max(la),k[1]] for k,la in key.iteritems()]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an OrderedDict and replace the value if we find a sublist with the same name with a larger second subelement:

```
l = [['john', 14, 'USA'],['john', 27, 'USA'],['paul', 17, 'USA'],['paul', 36, 'USA']]

from collections import OrderedDict
d = OrderedDict()

for sub in l:
    name = sub[0]
    if name in d:
        if sub[1] > d[name][1]:
            d[name] = sub
    else:
        d[name] = sub
print(list(d.values()))

[['john', 27, 'USA'], ['paul', 36, 'USA']]
```

This is `O(n)` as it does not have to sort the list which is `n log n` so  this will scale better than any method using sorted.

If order does not matter a normal dict will be fine:

```
d = {}
for sub in l:
    name = sub[0]
    if name in d:
        if sub[1] > d[name][1]:
            d[name] = sub
    else:
        d[name] = sub
print(d.values())
```

If you were going to sort using `operator.itemgetter` would be more efficient:

```
from operator import  itemgetter    
sorted(l,key=itemgetter(1))
```

If you wanted to sort the original list:

```
l.sort(key=itemgetter(1))
```

Answer (score 0):

trying my hand at incomprehensible level pythonic.

using list and dictionary comprehensions i sort, merge, and reformat

```
a = [['john', 14, 'USA'],['john', 27, 'USA'],['paul', 17, 'USA'],['paul', 36, 'USA']]

b = sorted(a, key=lambda x: x[0])
c = { x[0] : x[1:len(x)] for x in b }

result = [[n] + c[n] for n in c]
```